# Where can I find more information about specific CouchDB testing errors?

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon

I'm getting errors in the futon testing suite on attachments and attachment_paths and can't seem to find any information on potential causes.  Any ideas?  I'll paste the errors I get below, just in case that helps.

attachments error:

```
Assertion failed: binAttDoc2._attachments["foo2.txt"].content_type == "text/plain;charset=utf-8"
Assertion failed: xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Type") == "text/plain;charset=utf-8"
Assertion failed: xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Type") == "text/plain;charset=utf-8"
Assertion failed: xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Type") == "text/plain;charset=utf-8"
Assertion failed: xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Type") == "text/plain;charset=utf-8"
Assertion failed: xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Type") == "text/plain;charset=utf-8"
Assertion failed: xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Type") == "text/plain;charset=utf-8"
```

attachment_paths error:

```
Assertion failed: binAttDoc._attachments["foo/bar2.txt"].content_type == "text/plain;charset=utf-8"
Assertion failed: binAttDoc._attachments["foo/bar2.txt"].content_type == "text/plain;charset=utf-8"
Assertion failed: binAttDoc._attachments["foo/bar2.txt"].content_type == "text/plain;charset=utf-8"
Assertion failed: binAttDoc._attachments["foo/bar2.txt"].content_type == "text/plain;charset=utf-8"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're best off posting these to the CouchDB @user list, or asking on IRC. Due to idiosyncracies in browser JS implementations, and sometimes bugs, the test suite failures are often not related to CouchDB.

I usually run the test suite from a privacy mode to ensure that cache, cookies, logins etc are not contaminating each test run.

Once the main tests are completed, I re-run any failures manually.

The error reported above looks quite like you have some form of JSON prettyprinter running in the browser, which is sending a different header set to CouchDB than it usually expects.

Comment: Yeah, it does seem to be browser related.  This was in Chrome.  I tried FF4 and everything passed w/ flying colors.  Still wrapping my head around all of it, but your answer was very helpful in giving me places to seek further help.  Thanks!

Comment: Same results here, run tests in firefox (osx, firefox 18.02, couchdb 1.2.1) and all pass, safari and chrome failed.